# How to specify two variables through input, then change them

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the user to specify two variables, then change the last one to the first one.

```
print('Whats your move?')
move = raw_input('>>> ')
move = move.split()
move[1] = move[0]
move[0] = ' '
```

Sort of like that code, but instead of just changing the list, I want to actualy change the variables.

So if someone did inputed `f7 f6` it would change the variable `f6` to the same value at `f7`, and then turn `f7` to whitespace.

Is there a way to do this in python 2.7?

Comment: Any time you are thinking of dynamically accessing variables by name in Python you should rather be thinking about arrays and/or dictionaries instead. For example, given `board` that is a `dict`, `board[move[1]] = board[move[0]]; board[move[0]] = ' '`

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: Maybe unpacking `a, b = move.split()` can help?

Comment: @EPo I think OP actually wants to inject names into the global scope, depending on what the user put in.

Comment: It's *possible*, but in general, doing that sort of thing is a really bad idea. Instead, make `f6` and `f7` keys of a dict, and then it's really easy, eg `old, new = 'f7', 'f6'; my_dict[new] = my_dict[old]`